# Create a raster image from multiple vector layers within a specified polygon

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, vector, rasterization

In ArcGIS Pro 3.0 I am creating a map using 11 vector layers including point, line, and area features. I have it all symbolized and displaying nicely at the design scale, and would like to take that appearance and render rasters of it within specified areas.

The example image shows the symbolized vector layers with a black square overlaid. What I'm trying to do is create a raster with exactly the extents of the square that looks exactly how the vector layers are displaying. Essentially, merging the vector layers into a single flat image.

How would I go about doing this? I have only been able to find ways to convert a single vector layer, such as the Feature to Raster tool.

[image: Example]

Comment: In QGIS this can be done with one click by creating MBTiles...I believe the same thing in the ESRI world is called "Create Map Tile Package (Data Management)".